Streamlit + FastAPI : how to dealing with long running process (10min)?
I need to deal with the current issue :
in my frontend (streamlit), I'd like to get a file (such as excel), send it to my backend (with FastAPI). The backend will work with a BackgroundTasks during around 10min.
I need to get the result (like a processed dataframe) in my frontend and plot a graph.
How can I deal with this properly ?
My first thought is :

in the backend, get the file, start a backgroundtask, return a message saying "ok" and having a second path to get status of treatment and a third getting the actual result
in frontend, having a auto refresh in streamlit every minute and getting the status and, if status changed, getting the result

Is there a better way to do this ? Can I get a status of a backgroundtask ? (is there some id to deal with it) ?
Thank you

AFAIK streamlit doesn't accept incoming requests by itself so without setting up webhooks the solution you've described is the second best thing.
